# How to save a path with ~ into a variable?

Tags: shell, variable, tilde

I have these variables in my script:

```
TARGET=username
TARGET_DIR="~${TARGET}/.ssh"
```

I want the `TARGET_DIR` var to hold this path: `/home/username/.ssh` but to use `~` instead of `/home/`.
But when I run the script and try to make new `.ssh` dir under username it tells me:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘~username/.ssh’: No such file or directory
```

Even though the /home/username dirs exists.
If I do:     `TARGET_DIR="/home/${TARGET}/.ssh"`
it works.
How can I use the `~` sign in the variable?

Comment: ~ will refer to the users home directory i.e. /home/username. You would therefore not need to expand ~ but rather add home to TARGET_DIR so TARGET_DIR="/home/$TARGET/.ssh"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `bash`, `ash`, `mksh` and `yash` tilde expansion occurs before parameter expansion, so that can't work.

You can use `ksh93` or `zsh` instead here, or resort to `eval`:

```
user=username # making sure it's a valid username
eval "user_home=~$user"
target_dir=$user_home/.ssh
```

If your system has a `getent` command (quite common nowadays), you can also use:

```
user_home=$(getent -- passwd "$user" | cut -d: -f6)
```

Or use `perl`:

```
user_home=$(perl -le 'for (@ARGV) {
  @u = getpwnam$_ or die "No such user: $_\n";
  print $u[7]}' -- "$user")
```

Which would also work with users with uncommon characters in their username (like space which zsh's `~$user` but not `ksh93`'s `~"$user"` would also have a problem with).

Comment: thanks, but didn't you meant the other way? That param expansion happens before the ~ expansion? Otherwise, it makes no sense to me. I would like if you can clarify that for me, please.

Comment: @lakerda, no. If param expansion happened before, then `~$user` would be expanded to `~username` and then to `/home/userhome`. But it's the other way round. If you had a user whose username was `$user`, `~$user` would expand to the home directory of that user (in `bash`, not in `ash`/`mksh`/`yash` where that `~$user` is simply not recognised as a tilde expansion at all as they consider `$` is not a valid character in a user name. As currently written, the POSIX spec would imply that only `bash` is conformant in that regard (but not conformant in others, the POSIX spec is not clear)).